# How to programatically set String input of TextEditor in Eclipse plug-in?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

**What I want:** I want to write JUnit tests for my Eclipse editor plug-in. For this I want to set up an instance of my `TextEditor` extension. Then I want to set the input of this `TextEditor` from a String, so that the content of the String is the input of the editor instance. Then I want to run some tests and assert that the editor marks errors and so on.

**Where I fail:** I don't know how to set up the input of the editor from a String. The only function the editor has to do so is `setInput(IEditorInput input)`, but I don't know how to create an `ÌEditorInput` with a String as it's content.

Is there any possibility to do so and, if not, any other way to set the input of the editor to a given String?

Comment: Quite a lot of the workings of an editor depend on the exact details of the editor input. For example most editors like to have an `IFileEditorInput` rather than just an `IEditorInput`. So to really test the editor properly you need to give it a workspace file.

Comment: and how do I create a workspace file with a given string as input?

Comment: You use the `create` method of `IFile`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either create a (workspace) file as [Greg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2670892/greg-449) suggested or implement a specialized `IEditorInput` and open a text editor with this input.

For example:

```java
// uninteresting methods left out for brevity

class StringEditorInput implements IStorageEditorInput {
  @Override
  public boolean exists() {
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public IStorage getStorage() throws CoreException {
    return new StringStorage();
  }
}

class StringStorage implements IStorage {
  @Override
  public InputStream getContents() throws CoreException {
    return new ByteArrayInputStream( "Hello editor!".getBytes( StandardCharsets.UTF_8 ) );
  }
}

String editorId = "org.eclipse.ui.DefaultTextEditor";
IWorkbenchPage page = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();
IEditorPart editor = IDE.openEditor( page , new StringEditorInput(), editorId );
```