# How to display / edit / save a string using an eclipse text editor into a RCP application?

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp

I'm working on an Eclipse 4 RCP application. I have a perspective with some parts and an editor. The editor's purpose is to open, edit and save a String.

1. How can I open an editor that takes as input the string? Most of the `IDE.openEditor(...)` implementations take an IFile as input but I don't want to use a file as an intermediary.
2. After editing the content of the editor, how can I save it into a string? when using a file the editor saves its content directly into the file.

Comment: You say 'Eclipse 4 RCP' - is this a pure e4 RCP (using an Application.e4xmi and only plug-ins in the the org.eclipse.e4.rcp feature)? Anything else (such as using `IDE` or `IFile`) is a 3.x compatability mode RCP.

Comment: For a 3.x compatability RCP you could use the variant of `IDE.openEditor` which takes an `IEditorInput` with a suitable `IEditorInput` implementation. I can't find a suitable existing editor input implementation so you would have to write one - which requires quite a lot of work researching what is needed.

Comment: Yes, it an e4 RCP using Application.e4xmi but we use the compatibility layer as some elements like the editor itself are from 3.x.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. From [Rüdiger Herrmann](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42027933/how-to-programatically-set-string-input-of-texteditor-in-eclipse-plug-in) and [greg-449](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27626959/get-the-current-source-code-of-an-eclipse-editor?rq=1) I was able to build this prototype.

```
class StringEditorInput implements IStorageEditorInput {

    private IStorage storage;

    public StringEditorInput(IStorage storage) {

        this.storage = Objects.requireNonNull(storage, "Storage object cannot be null.");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean exists() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public IStorage getStorage() throws CoreException {
        return storage;
    }

   /* Uninteresting methods left out for brevity */
}

class StringStorage implements IStorage {

    private String content;

    public StringStorage(String content) {

        this.content = Objects.requireNonNull(content, "The new content string cannot be null.");
    }

    @Override
    public InputStream getContents() throws CoreException {
        return new ByteArrayInputStream(content.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    }

    /* Uninteresting methods left out for brevity */
}

/**
 * Set the text in the PDDL editor.
 *
 * @param text
 *            PDDL code to show in the editor.
 */
public void setEditorText(String text) {

    String editorId = "pl.poznan.put.cs.gui4pddl.PDDLEditor";
    IWorkbenchPage page = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();

    try {
        editor = IDE.openEditor(page, new StringEditorInput(new StringStorage(text)), editorId);
    } catch (PartInitException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * Get the text currently displayed in the PDDL editor.
 *
 * @return PDDL code.
 */
public String getEditorText() {

    IWorkbenchPage page = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();
    page.saveEditor(editor, false);

    String editorText = "";

    if (editor instanceof ITextEditor) {
        ITextEditor textEditor = (ITextEditor) editor;

        IDocumentProvider provider = textEditor.getDocumentProvider();

        IEditorInput input = editor.getEditorInput();

        IDocument document = provider.getDocument(input);

        editorText = document.get();
    }

    return editorText;
}
```

Note that `setEditorText(String text)` and `getEditorText()` are somehow connected to the buttons Open and Save in my RCP application.